# Conditionally incrementing a variable in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Below is my script :

```
increment
    ${delCount}=    Set Variable    0
    :FOR    ${loopIndex}    INRANGE    0    8
    \    Log    ${loopIndex}
    \    ${delCount}=    Run Keyword If    '${loopIndex}'=='${3}'    Run Keywords    ${delCount+3}
    \    ...    ELSE IF    '${loopIndex}'=='${6}'    Run Keywords    ${delCount+6}
    \    ...    ELSE    Sleep    1s
    Log    ${delCount}
```

All I need to do is to increment the variable when the condition satisfies. How to go about this?
I tried below :

Run Keywords    Evaluate    ${delCount}+${3}

Run Keywords    ${delCount}=    Set Variable     ${delCount}+${3}

Run Keyword    Evaluate    ${delCount}

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
${delCount}=    Set Variable    0
:FOR    ${loopIndex}    IN RANGE    0    8
\    Log    ${loopIndex}
\    ${delCount}=    Run Keyword If    ${loopIndex} == 3    Evaluate    ${loopIndex} + ${delCount}
\    ...    ELSE IF    ${loopIndex} == 6    Evaluate    ${delCount} + 6
\    ...    ELSE    Sleep    1s
Log    ${delCount}
```

Comment: When `loopIndex` is not 3 or 6, `delCount` will be set to `None` - because that's the return value of `Sleep  1s`. So in the final ELSE substitute that with `Set Variable    ${delCount}` - and that will preserve its current value. Thus one more condition will be needed for the Sleep - `\ Run Keyword If    ${loopIndex} not in (3, 6)    Sleep    1s`, and it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
${delCount} | Set Variable If | ${loopIndex} == 3 | ${delCount} + ${loopIndex} | ${delCount}

${delCount} | Set Variable If | ${loopIndex} == 6 | ${delCount} + 6 | ${delCount}
```